# Bean Validation ADF and myFaces extVal on weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: weblogic, bean-validation, jsf-1.2, oracle-adf, weblogic11g

I have tried to use myFaces extVal Bean Validation on Weblogic 10.3.6 (JSF 1.2, patched JPA to 2.0) and with ADF Faces.
Is it possible to use "ADF Faces" and "Apache myFaces extVal Bean Validation" together on Weblogic 10.3.6?

I habe tried to add following libraries:

```
asm-1.5.3.jar
cglib-2.1_3.jar
myfaces-extval-bean-validation-1.2.5.jar
myfaces-extval-core-1.2.5.jar
myfaces-extval-property-validation-1.2.5.jar
myfaces-extval-trinidad-support-1.2.5.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

The result is following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:    
org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.CoreRenderingContext cannot be cast to oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderingContext
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.getRichRenderingContext(RichRenderer.java:1230)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1259)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:341)
at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.validator.core.renderkit.ExtValLazyRendererProxy.encodeEnd(ExtValLazyRendererProxy.java:77)
at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.validator.core.renderkit.ExtValRendererWrapper.encodeEnd(ExtValRendererWrapper.java:312)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:767)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:911)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:367)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:222)
at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.validator.core.startup.ExtValLifecycleWrapper.render(ExtValLifecycleWrapper.java:79)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

So the reason is that I have mixed up ADF implementation with myFaces implementation, right?
So I suppose it is not possbile to use extVal for JSF 1.2 with ADF on Weblogic 10.3.6.

I have seen following site: 
http://buttso.blogspot.de/2011/05/jsf-20-jpa-20-and-bean-validation-on.html
There JSF 2.0, JPA 2.0 and BeanValidation are used on Weblogic 10.3.
So in my case it is not possible to use JSF 2.0.
And I have to use ADF (Faces).

I just want to make sure that there is no other possibility to get it work.

Regards,

Max

Answer (score 0):

"There JSF 2.0, JPA 2.0 and BeanValidation are used on Weblogic 10.3. So in my case it is not possible to use JSF 2.0. And I have to use ADF (Faces)."

Actually its JDeveloper 11g R2 (11.1.2.2) that supports JSF 2.0 with ADF Faces. Though JDeveloper 11g R2 is based on WLS 10.3.6 it requires a spcific patch from customer support to work. So you can upgrade to JSF 2.0 and ADF Faces but you need a speific JDeveloper (thus ADF Faces) version and a patch